# subversion reinstall (source, Makefile, etc)

Tags: ubuntu, svn, uninstall, reinstall, makefile

I installed subversion from source. I forgot the --with-ssl option when running ./configure. Now, I reconfigured and reinstalled, but the binary doesn't seem to change.

How do I uninstall and reinstall with new configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You have reconfigured, reinstall but did you recompile first, before reinstalling? Reconfiguring alone isn't enough.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: In other words, `./configure --...`, *then* `make`, then `make install`